# How can I add block through XML layout file, and not programmatically, through controller?

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-1, xml

How can I add a block through XML layout file, and not programaticaly, through controller?

I have my block and I want to use it in a template that already exists (catalog/category/view.phtml).

How can I do this without going in and changing a controller, and without changing the catalog/category/view.phtml directly?

I want to add this block somewhere in an already existing template through XML, and not programatically.

This is part of my block:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Myblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this -> setTemplate("mynamespace_mymodule/myblock.phtml");
        return parent::_construct();

    }

    public function getItemsByCategoryAndUseState($category, $use_state) {
        return "some used or new items";
    }
}
```

This is config.xml of my module:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Mynamespace_Mymodule>
        <version>3.0.0.1</version>
    </Mynamespace_Mymodule>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <mynamespace_mymodule>
            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
        </mynamespace_mymodule>
    </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <file>mynamespace_mymodule.xml</file>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>

</frontend>
```

This is my package/theme/layout/mynamespace_mymodule.xml:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_view> 
        <reference name="product_list"> 
            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/myblock" name="myblock" after="-" /> 
        </reference> 
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: share your block and XML where you want to reuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add block with this xml code

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="mymodule/myblock"  after="-" />
     </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

add this is `<frontend>` tag not in `<global>`

```
     <frontend>
      <layout>
        <updates>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <file>mynamespace_mymodule.xml</file>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
        </updates>
      </layout>
    </frontend>
```

Comment: This is the exact answer to the question.

Comment: And what does the after=-= mean?

Comment: Something is wrong. I am not getting the output from the block when I added this in config.xml of the module:
<frontend>
...
     <layout>
         <updates>
             <catalog_category_view>
                    <reference name="content">
                        <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/myblock" name="useditems" after="-" />
                        
                    </reference>
                </catalog_category_view>
         </updates>
     </layout>
 </frontend>
 
 ...
    
</config>

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic which file your are editing if it is layout file simple add this code `<catalog_category_view> <reference name="content"> <block type="thinkopen_overwriter/filteredbooks" name="usedbooksincategory" after="-" /> </reference> </catalog_category_view>` layout file is in`app/design/frontend/spacename/themename/layout/thier are layout file`

Comment: See my comment above. It didn't work. I added this in my design/frontend/package/theme/layout/mynamespace_mymodule.xml:
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <frontend>
     <layout>
         <updates>
             <catalog_category_view>
                    <reference name="content">
                        <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/myblock" name="nameofmyblock" after="-" />
                        
                    </reference>
                </catalog_category_view>
         </updates>
     </layout>
 </frontend>
</layout>

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic this code it totally wrong you can check `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml` for the reference of layout

Comment: Which code is totally wrong? Your code for sure.

Comment: both code try this code `<?xml version="1.0"?><layout version="0.1.0"> <catalog_category_view> <reference name="content"> <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/myblock" name="nameofmyblock" after="-" /> </reference> </catalog_category_view> </layout>`

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: now you have to addd you config.xml xml so i can check you call the your xml in that? try to put this code in `page.xml ` check it is working or not

Comment: I put it in page.xml and it's not working. My block is not displaying.

Comment: My bad, it's displaying. It shows when I put it in page.xml but not whenI put it in mynamespace_mymodule.xml under layouts dir.

Comment: did you define your layout? in config.xml

Comment: Yes I did. I tried putting this in both <global> and <frontend> tags in my config.xml and it didn't work:
<layout>
            <updates>
                <mynamespace_mymodule>
                    <file>mynamespace_mymodule.xml</file>
                </mynamespace_mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>

Comment: can you paste one more question with your `config.xml` because this question got messy with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49097/discussion-between-fme-extensions-and-vladimir-despotovic).

Comment: You need to create `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mynamespace_mymodule.xml` and add the first part of the code in above answer there. This will be merged with your theme package XML.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it partially by using methods of the block in template. I just:

1. Created the block
2. Declared the block in module's config.xml
3. Using it in the template (a .phtml file) like so:
4. ```
   echo $this -> getLayout() 
       -> createBlock('mymodule/myblock') 
       -> toHtml();
   ```

I want to do it just with .XML layout updates though.

Comment: which **url** you trying to set your template?

Comment: This url: http://127.0.0.1/mysite/firstcategory.html

Comment: you want to set template for `category page`?

Comment: I don't want to change the template file template/catalog/category/view.phtml. I would like to add block to the template and layout by using XML.